# Test if all the Ethernet Cards in the machine has Link

Tags: linux, bash, networking

How can I check in bash scripting if the ethernet cards are linked in a Linux OS

Comment: That's going to depend a lot on what OS you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some form like this may work for you

```sh
ip -o link | grep NO_CARRIER
```

This checks to make sure every network interface (even logical ones) has a connection

- `ip` from iproute2
- `-o` show output on one line (per interface) to simplify for `grep`
- `link` show information about links